# "Cannot be resolved to a type" when attempting to use Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

when i run following code it shows error that scanner cannot be resolved to type. i checked that jre is installed and version is 1.7 what else do i need to check ? please help.

```
public class student { 

String name;
int rollno;
public void get(String nm, int rno) 
{ name=nm;
rollno=rno;
}
public void  display()
{  System.out.println("Name of student is :" +name);
System.out.println("Roll no of student is :" +rollno);
}  
public static void main(String args[])
{ 
int i ;
int r1;
String n1;
student obj[]= new student[10];
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
obj[i]= new student();
}

for(i=0;i<10; i++)
{  System.out.println("Enter name:");
n1=sc.next();
sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter roll no :");
r1=sc.nextInt();


obj[i].get(n1,r1) ;
obj[i].display() ;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to also import the class itself. At the very top of the file, above `public class student`, you need to add:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

In addition, I'd like to pose a few more possible corrections:

- Class names should be `PascalCase`
- Your code should have consistent indentation. Ctrl+Shift+F is your friend here.

Comment: yeah i added that . still same issue

Comment: Is the JRE's `rt.lib` on the build path?

Answer (score 5):

Just use `import java.util.Scanner;` or use `import java.util.*;`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code myself and it works. Therefore, it is a configuration problem. Since you tried to import java.util.Scanner, as hexafraction suggested, then I suppose the JRE is not properly configured.

Try :

- Right clicking your project name -> Click properties -> Click Java Build Path
- Select the libraries tab
- Click on add class folder (at the right) then select your Class.

Edit : Even tho it would not really solve the problem, copy the src folder in a new project would probably solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code's compilation level by right click your project in eclipse and click properties.

It might point to 1.6 or lower. If it is the case point it to 1.7

This might solve your problem.

I hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your package > Navigate to properties > Click on java build path > Click on libraries tab > Click on add library > Select JRE System library > Click on next > Click on Finish > Click on apply and Close.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn35M.png)
It should work.... I hope so :)

Answer (score 0):

Just type `sc.close();` just after the last third curly bracket `}` to close the scanner at the end...your issue will be resolved!

Answer (score -1):

Keep Messing with the options you get in eclipse , for example like try block for scanner and so on.. it will fix itself after a while. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Hi Swaroop, glad to have you and your willingness to share knowledge. You might want to replace "messing with the options" with actual steps to solve the issue. Stuff like import statements or JRE settings