# Program won't run scanner cannot be resolved

Tags: java

This is the code I have so far and this is only one file of multiple ones that all belong to the same program.

As soon as I want to compile and check my errors eclipse tells me that it cannot resolve the scanner and I have no idea how to fix this problem nor what it exactly means.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PieShop {
    static FoodItem foodItem = new FoodItem();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner_in.consoleLine("Enter Food item File name:");
        foodItem.foodItemFile=new File(Scanner_in.getConsole());
        foodItem.addFoodItem();
        foodItem.displayAll();
        foodItem.choices();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner_in` is never defined. This won't compile.

Comment: You imported a `Scanner`... Did you want to make a `new Scanner()` at some point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner cannot be resolved to a type in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819174/scanner-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-in-eclipse)

Comment: @HarshaW Not the same solution.

Comment: you have to instantiate Scanner

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work fine provided that you pass right value to scanner source

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PieShop {
    static FoodItem foodItem = new FoodItem();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Scanner_in = new Scanner(source);
        Scanner_in.consoleLine("Enter Food item File name:");
        foodItem.foodItemFile=new File(Scanner_in.getConsole());
        foodItem.addFoodItem();
        foodItem.displayAll();
        foodItem.choices();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the correct way if you wan to read the input from the console:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PieShop {

    private static FoodItem foodItem = new FoodItem();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Initialize scanner
        System.out.println("Enter Food item File name:"); // Print yourtext
        foodItem.foodItemFile = new File(scanner.nextLine()); // Read from scanner
        foodItem.addFoodItem();
        foodItem.displayAll();
        foodItem.choices();
    }
}
```